# Confused about the `move-result-wide` smali instruction

Tags: android, reverse-engineering, dalvik, smali

The following smali codes, trying to move a 64-bit result to the register `v4`. But the size of the `v4` is 32-bit. So how does the `v4` store the value?

```
invoke-virtual {v0}, Landroid/location/Location;->getTime()J
move-result-wide v4
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `move-result-wide vx` instruction will move the long/double result value of the previous method invocation into `vx`,`vx+1`.

See [Dalvik opcodes](http://pallergabor.uw.hu/androidblog/dalvik_opcodes.html).